# compute S transform and its square value in matlab

Tags: matlab, wavelet, time-frequency

let us consider following code  taken from

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45848-stockwell-transform--s-transform-/content/stran.m

to compute S transform, here is my code

```
function ST=stran(h)
% Compute S-Transform without for loops
%%% Coded by Kalyan S. Dash %%%
%%% IIT Bhubaneswar, India %%%
[~,N]=size(h); % h is a 1xN one-dimensional series
nhaf=fix(N/2);
odvn=1;
if nhaf*2==N;
    odvn=0;
end
f=[0:nhaf -nhaf+1-odvn:-1]/N;
Hft=fft(h);
%Compute all frequency domain Gaussians as one matrix
invfk=[1./f(2:nhaf+1)]';
W=2*pi*repmat(f,nhaf,1).*repmat(invfk,1,N);
G=exp((-W.^2)/2); %Gaussian in freq domain
% End of frequency domain Gaussian computation
% Compute Toeplitz matrix with the shifted fft(h)
HW=toeplitz(Hft(1:nhaf+1)',Hft);
% Exclude the first row, corresponding to zero frequency
HW=[HW(2:nhaf+1,:)];
% Compute Stockwell Transform
ST=ifft(HW.*G,[],2); %Compute voice
%Add the zero freq row
st0=mean(h)*ones(1,N);

ST=[st0;ST];

end
```

and consider following chirp signal

```
>> t = 0:0.001:2;
x = chirp(t,100,1,200,'quadratic');
```

i need  confirmation that i am doing correctly following things

```
>> ST=stran(x);
>> plot(abs(ST))
```

?

picture is here
[image]

Comment: thanks my friend,it seems more  correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer:

I don't have much idea of the s-transform, but AFAIK the result of it is a 3D signal (as you can clearly see in the size of ST), so you may want to do `imagesc(abs(ST))` or `surf(abs(ST),'linestyle','none')` instead of plot.

In your figure you have plotted 1000 lines, that's why its so chaotic.

Using

`imagesc(abs(ST))`
[image]